# Is it possible to access UIView in MainWindow.xib using tag

Tags: iphone

There are 2 UIView in my MainWindow.Xib
One is the outlet of RootViewController view, another UIView is that I hope to access using tag (123) from the source codes of RootViewController.
If the second UIView is the sub view of the first view, I know I can use

```
[self.view viewWithTag:123];
```

But I do not know how to handle this case when the UIView that hope to be accessed is not the sub view of current view.

[image]

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Comment: why not create an outlet for the second view in RootViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tag` is specific to a `UIView` hierarchy (see **Return value** on UIView's `viewWithTag:`). Since there is no hierarchy between two separate views, you cannot use it.

Instead, do what phix23 suggests and add an `IBOutlet` for your second view in your `RootViewController`, i.e.:

**RootViewController.h**

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {
  // ...
}

// @synthesize in RootViewController.m (don't forget to dealloc)
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *secondView;
```

Then hook that up in your XIB-file.